# Pushing array with object that deletes it self by getting "this" property of parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, timer, closures

Code:

```
particles.push(new function() {
    this.x = 500
    this.y = 500
    this.vx = 2
    this.vy = 2
    this.radius = 5
    this.expireTimer = setTimeout(function(self) {
        return function() {
            particles.splice(particles.indexOf(self), 1)
        }
    }(this), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500)
})
```

My question is: Is there any other way to get the actual `this` attribute in this case? Is there any way to get `this` in this case without using `new function()` and pushing the array with the object as you would normally, like `particles.push({x: 23})` instead of `particles.push(new function() {this.x = 23})`?

Comment: Thanks for that edit Semir Turgay!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer from inside an object literal to the object itself, unless you have a variable to which the object is assigned to:

```
var obj = {
    timer: setTimeout(function () {
        doSomething(obj);
    }, 1000)     
};
```

In your case, if your main goal is a simpler syntax, I would suggest to write a helper function, that takes care of particle creation/destruction:

```
function createParticle(particle) {
    particles.push(particle);
    particle.expireTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        particles.splice(particles.indexOf(particle), 1);
    },Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 500);
}
```

With this function, you can create new particles by simply calling this:

```
createParticle({
    x: 500,
    y: 500,
    vx: 2,
    vy: 2,
    radius: 5
});
```